# Is it possible to create an array on the heap at run-time, and then allocate more space whenever needed?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-arrays

Lets say I do

```
char *a;
a = new char[4];
```

Now, is it possible to extend the size of the array further?

Say I want to keep any values I put inside `a[0]` to `a[3]` but now I want more space for `a[4]` and `a[5]` etc. Is that possible in C++?

---

At first I felt like maybe I could just make:

```
char* a[10];
a[0] = new char[size];
```

Whenever more space is needed I can go to `a[1]` and allocate more space. This is the only alternative I can think of at the moment.

Comment: why don't you use std::vector?

Comment: It's a shame, but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3105001/961353

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible in C++. You have to allocate a new area and copy the old into the new.

However, C++ have other facilities, like `std::vector`, that alleviates the need to manually handle these things.

Comment: Or,  if it doesn't need to be contiguous, [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) can avoid reallocations.

Comment: Thanks, a vector sounds like what I will want to use for this program.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of char* a , you can use char** a;

i.e.

```
char**  a = new char*[4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  (*a)[i] = new char(i);   /* feed values to array */

/* now you need a[4]? no problem */
char tmp = (*a)[3];
a[3] = new char[2];

a[3][0] = tmp;
a[3][1] = xyz;    /* this is you a[4] */
```

Though this is a work around, I would suggest to used vector.

Comment: Line 3 does not make any sense to me.

Comment: -1 This changes the semantics a lot and will incur a significant performance penalty.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain it was just a work around, of course performance overheads are there, and vector is recommended.

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain the question wasnt about performance, it is not important here, over-pre-optimization : evil of everything

Comment: @cf16 Well, let's be sensible. Pre-optimisation is bad, but you have 2 options on the table: allocate a new array and copy or fiddle around with an array of arrays. The first is both easier and more performant in most cases. Besides, the solution here was to use a vector.