# Does an allocation hint get used?

Tags: c++, allocator

I was reading [Why is there no reallocation functionality in C++ allocators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3105001/961353) and [Is it possible to create an array on the heap at run-time, and then allocate more space whenever needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15379903/961353), which clearly state that reallocation of a dynamic array of objects is impossible.

However, in *The C++ Standard Library* by Josuttis, it states an Allocator, `allocator`, has a function `allocate` with the following syntax

```
pointer allocator::allocate(size_type num, allocator<void>::pointer hint = 0)
```

where the `hint` has an implementation defined meaning, which may be used to help improve performance.

Are there any implementations that take advantage of this?

Answer (score 4):

I have gained significant performance advantages for iteration times on small scalar types in my [plf::colony](http://www.plflib.org) c++ container using hints with std::allocator under Visual Studio 2010-2013 (iteration speed increased by ~21%), and much smaller speedups under GCC 5.1. So it's safe to say that with those compilers and std::allocator, it makes a difference. But the difference will be compiler-dependent. I am not aware of the ratio of hint-ignoring to hint-observing allocators.

Comment: I thought the hint was to provide alignment, like a forward aligned pointer. Are you maybe aware of how would this be possible on a modern C++ standard `std::allocator`?

Comment: @Nikos Read the reference please
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator_traits/allocate/

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how you used hint and why it might have increased performance?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about specific implementations, but note that the allocator isn't allowed to return the hint pointer value before it's been passed to `deallocate`. So that can't be used as a primitive operation to form a `reallocate`.

The Standard says the hint must have been returned by a previous call to `allocate`. It says "The use of [the hint] is unspecified, but it is
intended as an aid to locality." So if you're allocating and releasing a sequence of similar-sized blocks on one thread, you might pass the previously-freed value to avoid cache contention between microprocessor caches.

Otherwise, when CPU B sees that you're using memory addresses still in CPU A's cache (even that memory contains objects that were destroyed according to C++), it must forward the junk data over the bus. Better to let CPU A and B each reuse their own respective cached addresses.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 states, in **20.6.9.1 allocator members**:

> 4 - [ *Note:* In a container member function, the address of an adjacent element is often a good choice to pass for the `hint` argument. — *end note* ]
>   [...]
>   6 - [...] The use of `hint` is unspecified, but intended as an aid
>   to locality if an implementation so desires.

Allocating new elements adjacent or close to existing elements in memory can aid performance by improving locality; because they are usually cached together, nearby elements will tend to travel together up the memory hierarchy and will not evict each other.

Comment: Ah, so it's for allocating objects next to each other rather than reallocating an existing object?

Comment: You can't just pass the next available address. The hint must have been obtained from a previous call to `allocate`.