# Is it fair to always recommend std::vector over realloc?

Tags: c++, realloc

From [Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#realloc):

> If you feel the need for realloc() - and many do - then consider using
>   a standard library vector.

I'll preface my question by agreeing that `std::vector` is better for many reasons, and I personally would always choose to use it over writing my own dynamic arrays with C memory allocation.

*But*, `std::vector` fragments memory as it grows because C++ has no equivalent of `realloc` (**edit** To clarify, I know that `std::vector`'s storage is contiguous and won't get fragmented, I mean fragmentation of the memory space caused by allocating and deallocating, which `realloc` can avoid by extending an existing allocation). So is it fair to always recommend it over `realloc`? With great care, couldn't you write something that works just like `std::vector` but using C allocation functions, which has the possibility to grow its memory without moving its address and copying existing elements, making it as good or better in terms of fragmentation and performance?

And relatedly (bonus question!), *why* doesn't C++ have an equivalent to `realloc`? It seems like an odd thing to omit in a language that is so focused on performance. The section in Bjarne's FAQ has exactly that title (minus emphasis), but the answer doesn't address the 'why'. Was it just an accidental omission? Is there some fundamental incompatibility with how `new`/`delete` work? Does it not really give the benefits it seems to in practice?

**Edit**: ok, so I had neglected to consider the C nastiness of `realloc` - `std::vector` can't be rewritten using `realloc` because it only works with PODs, doesn't throw and so on. Perhaps a POD-only container written to deal with the nastiness would be a good idea for some situations. In any case though, the more interesting question becomes: would `std::vector` benefit from a C++ equivalent of `realloc`, which has (more or less) been answered here:

[Does std::vector *have* to move objects when growing capacity? Or, can allocators "reallocate"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003233/does-stdvector-have-to-move-objects-when-growing-capacity-or-can-allocator?lq=1)

Sadly, the answer seems to be "yes, but the standards committee didn't vote it in". Here's hoping.

Comment: Source that confirms that std::vector fragments memory? If that was the case, returning the data pointer wouldn't be safe.

Comment: why do you think std::vector resize fragments more than realloc? If you used realloc for doing a c-style vector, std::vector will work the same way, and possibly better because it may be implemented with a clever growth strategy which minimizes fragmentation.

Comment: A partial answer to your question is in [Does std::vector *have* to move objects when growing capacity? Or, can allocators “reallocate”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003233/does-stdvector-have-to-move-objects-when-growing-capacity-or-can-allocator)

Comment: realloc can fragment memory as much as std::vector.

Comment: By 'fragments memory' I mean the rest of the address space, not its own memory - any time it allocates a new block and deallocates the old block, it's contributing to fragmentation. `realloc` has the ability to expand an existing block though, which is surely as good or better than that?

Comment: @Ben: In this context, "fragmentation" means leaving gaps in the heap by allocating one block then freeing another, which can reduce the amount of usable blocks available from the heap. Of course, the memory used by the vector is a single contiguous block, since that's required by its specification.

Comment: Have you tried to search SO for existing answers to your question? There are several. If they don't satisfy you, cite one or two and explain why.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, none of them are quite the same. I can add some links if that's helpful.

Comment: Oh, then in that case I agree with galinette. I don't see why realloc would do a better job.

Comment: @galinette Yes, it *can*, but it also might not, that's my point. It's no worse than `std::vector` but might be better.

Comment: @BenHymers: "no worse than `std::vector`" - apart from only working for trivial types, and not giving you any control over the allocation strategy.

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md

Comment: @manlio Excellent foresight! I saw that question but didn't realise it was relevant until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Direct comparison

```
                        |  std::vector     | C memory functions
------------------------+------------------+------------------------
default capacity        | undefined        | undefined
default grow            | towards capacity | undefined
deterministic capacity  | available        | no
deterministic grow      | available        | no
deterministic mem.-move | available        | no
non-POD types           | yes              | f***ing no (*)
no-throw                | no               | yes
```

`deterministic mem.-move` follows from `deterministic capacity/grow`. It is when `realloc` and `std::vector` have to move their stored elements to a new memory location.

I think the (available) determinism with regards to memory moving is doubly important when you consider moving (smart) references of any kind.

<sub>NOTE: In this respect, I use the term "deterministic" with respect to my source codes lifetime, i.e. its lifetime across different versions of different libraries with different compile flags, etc..</sub>

---

### Source

It does fragment memory as much as `realloc` does:

> #### Class template vector overview [vector.overview]
>
> The elements of a
>   vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`

In other words, the memory used is in one piece.

The one big difference is that `realloc` can actually increase allocated memory portions without having ordered it to do so, however, it is not required to do so (`man 3 realloc`):

> #### man 3 realloc
>
> The  realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will
>          be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes.  If  the  new
>          size  is  larger  than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized.  If ptr is NULL, then the call is
>          equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is not NULL, then the call
>          is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), cal‐
>          loc() or realloc().  **If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.**

So it can increase the size, but is not required to.

A `std::vector` carries not only a `size`, but also a `capacity`. If you know beforehand you will need a big `vector`, yet you cannot initialize everything right now, you are entitled to increase the capacity of your vector like so:

```
std::vector<T> vec(32);
vec.reserve(1024);
// vec has size 32, but reserved a memory region of 1024 elements
```

So, unlike `realloc`, the moment when reallocations occur can be deterministic with `std::vector`.

To answer your question: Because there is `std::vector`, `realloc` is not needed. And, `realloc` is not allowed for non-POD types; attempts to use `malloc`, `free` and `realloc` directly on non-PODs yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: By fragmentation I mean of the address space, not of the vector itself - allocating a new block and deallocating the old one will leave a 'hole' whereas extending the existing allocation will not. I know that it's not required to, but it has the option to, and that's what interests me.

Comment: well realloc is still needed, as these are not the same things. And realloc can never throw.

Comment: @channel: But _needed_ for what? Good point about throwing, I added that to my table.

Comment: @BenHymers: But `realloc` could leave behind holes, too?

Comment: Ok, you're absolutely correct that C `realloc` has many problems, I hadn't considered those before asking my question. So how's about if there was a C++ equivalent of it which acted more like `new` and handled PODs, exceptions and so on; could `vector` not benefit from that?

Comment: @phresnel Yes, *could* but also could not. That's what I'm getting at :) if there's enough free space to expand the vector into, why not make use of it?

Comment: -1 Bad answer... the meaningful issue is whether a C++ type can use realloc internally to do potentially expand memory use in place, not a comparison of raw `realloc` vs `vector`.

Comment: @Tony D: I agree I may not be explicit enough, but it answers `So is it fair to always recommend it over realloc?`. Really worth a -1?

Comment: @TonyD Sadly the question I asked wasn't as interesting as that since I didn't think that far ahead - see my edit :) phresnel answered my question very well.

Comment: @phresnel: I don't think the question makes a lot of sense, and in trying to answer it you've written some stuff that's pretty meaningless.  For example: that someone reallocs/mallocs enouogh bytes for for N objects gives as "deterministic capacity" as a `vector` that `reserve`s similarly - some of your statements seem to imply no "current size" variable is being paired with the pointer to malloced memory.  There's nothing more deterministic about growth of a `vector` than `realloc` - either may fail due to memory exhaustion, or seem to succeed then fail as the memory is actually accessed.

Comment: @BenHymers: ok then... -1 to +1 :-).  Cheers.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but really it's only the comparison table and the last sentence that answer the question (could be summarised with "C memory allocation is nasty"). Tony's right in saying that the middle bit is unnecessary/unfair.

Comment: @TonyD: But how are `malloc/free/realloc` implementation details relevant to C++ application code? And how do those implementation details make it deterministic to the application when the application is not allowed to make use of those implementation details? How tight do you couple your applications to specific versions of specific standard library implementations on specific platforms using specific compile flags?

Comment: @Ben Hymers: I am still convinced that the middle part is not unfair, as I think it is the application's POV that counts wrt determinism, and not the library's. If the standards do not describe _when_ a _realloc_ does something, than I am in the school that says I can't rely on it; I then consider it indeterministic w.r.t. my code's lifetime. / I added a NOTE below the table.

Comment: @phresnel Non-deterministic, but in the right direction :) I mentioned in a comment on Mike Seymour's answer, "I'm happy if peformance and memory usage patterns are occasionally randomly better than normal". The whole point of bringing up `realloc` in the first place is that it has the option to extend an existing allocation, which sounds nice. Also note that I'm talking purely about when the vector needs to allocate, and that a `vector` using `realloc` would still allocate extra capacity and have a `reserve` method; it's just what happens when allocating that would differ.

Comment: This answer basically creates a straw-man: a container that uses `realloc` for every size change, instead of internally tracking capacity with separate capacity + size members.  Of course that would be terrible.  The right way to use `realloc` is to use `std::vector` *on top of it* (for trivially copyable types), instead of a new/copy/delete loop.  So you sometimes still get a copy on growth, but sometimes you get to avoid that perf hit and just expand an existing allocation.  Same worst case, much better average and *much* better best case, especially with lots of free virtual address space.

Answer (score 10):

`new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` are typically layered atop the C library allocation functions (ala `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`), possibly with an extra layer for small-object optimisations that use one `malloc`-ed region for quickly satisfying many small `new` requests.  This layering meant supporting `new` and `delete` took very little implementation effort on the part of early C++ library authors.

To utilise the in-place resizing functionality in `realloc` for C++, though, invasive changes to the `realloc` library function are needed so that if movement to a new memory region *is* required, the C++ library code gets the chance to copy-construct/destruct the objects being moved.  This could be done as:

- a callback happening after `realloc` realised a move was necessary, asking the C++ library to do the actual data movement instead of doing a `memcpy()` style bytewise copy, or
- as an additional resize-in-place-or-fail-without-moving function so the C++ library code could try that, then fall back on a `malloc` and proper/safe copy before deleteing the original objects and deallocating the original memory.

As most C library `realloc` functions lack any such hook/query facility, the C++ Standard - and Standard library - don't require it.  As Mehrdad points out, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105001/why-is-there-no-reallocation-functionality-in-c-allocators/3105769#3105769) documents SGI's acknowledgement of this issue.

Given the extensive use of C++ these days, it would - IMHO - make sense to ship a `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` implementation in the C++ library itself that does provide such a hook/query, so that C++ library authors who see utility in `realloc` can utilise it freely; that'd be a worthy candidate for inclusion in a future Standard.

> With great care, couldn't you write something that works just like std::vector but using C allocation functions, which has the possibility to grow its memory without moving its address and copying existing elements, making it as good or better in terms of fragmentation and performance?

As above - no - it's not possible to copy-construct/destruct objects with any amount of care without changes to the `realloc` API.

Comment: Excellent answer to the bonus question! Thank you!

Comment: -1: One major major C++ implementation does not make use of `realloc`: http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_opnt.cc?view=markup . Neither do I find anything relating `realloc` in the allocator/vector headers. However, maybe I did not research hard enough, so potential for +1 if you edit in some sources.

Comment: Was the "malloc/realloc/free" in the first sentence a typo and you meant "malloc/free"? I assumed it was since the answer makes more sense that way.

Comment: Let me remove my -1, too, as your latest edit adds quite some value. However, I would really value if you could name examples or sources for `new/delete` implementations that make use of `malloc/free/realloc` as you describe.

Comment: @phresnel: you're missing my point - on line 42 of the source you link you'll see `malloc` being called, proving the implementation **is** using C-library heap management, which means `realloc` could be used to attempt in-place growth of a memory region, but my answer explains that any actual use of `realloc` can't be coordinated with proper copy-construction/destruction for C++ objects in the "have to move" case, as the interface doesn't provide a pre-move hook nor tentative resize-only-if-you-can-do-it-in-place option.

Comment: @BenHymers: I did mean `malloc/realloc/free` - they're all related functions and indeed `realloc` can be used for initial memory allocation and for deallocation too, so a C++ library could only use `realloc` and never use `malloc` or `free` if it wanted to, even without ever trying to resize any existing allocation to anything other than 0 bytes (a `free`).  That would make for more confusing code though.  Summarily: `realloc(0, n) === malloc(n)`, and `realloc(p, 0) === free(p)`.

Comment: Yes, but what I don't see are for example the small-object optimizations, or, as you already name, any use of `realloc`. All I see in that implementation is a thin wrapper around `malloc` and `get_new_handler`. I actually approve of your second paragraph, though, which is why I removed by -1.

Comment: @TonyD Ok, that makes perfect sense when combined with your latest edit. Good answer, thanks again!

Comment: @phresnel: small-object optimisations aren't mandated - purely an implementation library choice.  Particularly for a system like Linux, GNU have the freedom to tune the C library routines to handle small objects quite nicely anyway, so there's less incentive to layer C++ library optimisations over them.  It's historically been more relevant for third party C++ compilers ported to OSes with varying quality C libraries.  In C, there tends to be fewer and larger allocations, with longer lifetimes, so the libraries were often less heavily tuned.

Comment: I realise that I took your first phrase for "Typically, they do small object optimizations", instead of "Possibly, they do so". While I would still appreciate actual source code examples or citations, there is nothing left preventing me to +1 your answer :) I think with one of the memory gurus as a ex team member (Ulrich Drepper, author of _What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory_ and _...: Linux Concurrency and Performance_) I very much trust `malloc` to be near optimal.

Comment: @phresnel: "what I don't see... any use of realloc" - my primary point in "typically layered atop C malloc/realloc/free" is that implementations are using the C heap facility associated with that three-function API, not specifically that you'd expect them to be using `realloc`, though the equivalences - `realloc(0, n) === malloc(n)` and `realloc(p, 0) === free(p)` and generality of `realloc` make it possible and occasionally elegant to use even when not attempting any in-place resizing, so a C++ implementation `could` currently use it for `new`/`delete`.

Comment: Yes, I basically just accidentally ignored your `possibly` right in the first phrase. However, I think the discussion in these comments was worth the mistake. You have good points here.

Comment: @phresnel: you trust *which implementation* of `malloc` to be near optimal - it's not a single thing ;-).  VMS, MVS, Cray, OS/360, embedded... all manner of systems out there, some tuned for typical use from COBOL, FORTRAN or C, others prioritorising less machine code or clean source code in malloc/free implementations over performance in edge cases.  I've seen a few small-object optimisation libraries - think there was code in Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design for that too? - but I'm not sure which C++ Std libs shipped their own implementation rather than trusting to malloc.  I'll dig! :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks, too. I think your answer should be upvoted more.

Comment: @TonyDelroy - for what it's worth, I think `realloc` could be used as the underlying mechanism for allocation during vector resizing, but it would have to be specialized only for trivially copyable types (something like what used to be called POD types). That's actually not that unusual: most standard library implementations already specialize containers for trivially copyable types so they can copy elements with `memcpy` - in addition to other specializations like skipping destruction if the destructor is trivial, etc.

Comment: ... well there is the little matter of the trivial copy allowance (you can bitwise copy these objects) applying specifically to `memcpy` but not explicitly to `realloc`. That's a minor clarification away. The more difficult problem is that the standard lets you _replace_ `operator new` and friends, which - assuming that the containers are defined to use them - makes it tough to use another allocation routine since it would change observable behavior (the replaced versions wouldn't be getting called any more).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: great points, though PODs can have scalar types which include pointers, and _if_ any pointers happen to be to elsewhere in the `vector` then they'd need to be updated during any memory move, so POD's not quite the right criteria.  There's certainly a set of types for which it's safe, but so many type traits these days it's tedious working out if there's already a suitable one.  Cheers

Comment: Well _trivially copyable_ is the criteria given in the standard, but I was wrong to call them "something like POD types". POD, now called "standard layout" types is all about the data layout and doesn't place restrictions on say what copy constructors are available. The set of trivially copyable types (whose members are neither a subset or superset of standard layout types) are defined exactly based on whether they can be bit-wise copy. The definition covers both implementation restrictions that would likely prevent copying (e.g,. no virtual functions) and ...

Comment: ... conditions that ensure that user-defined behavior (such as fixing up pointers or any other invariant) is not skipped: they cannot have user-defined copy or move constructors. In that case, copying an object byte-wise is "completely safe" and essentially all modern standard libraries take advantage of this in their container and `std::copy` implementations. By "completely safe" I mean that you get the same effect as if you had copied the object via the normal language mechanism of copy constructor or assignment.

Comment: @BeeOnRope "same effect" is the crucial bit there: in the scenario I mentioned - say `struct X { char c; const X* p_next; };` where the pointers in a number of `X`s were wired together into a logical linked list, it's not inherently safe to relocate them (the programmer would have to do some post-facto rewiring, or add a some constructor/assignment logic with a registry of other object instances).  That said, such a type wouldn't be safe in a vector increasing capacity anyway, so I shouldn't have side-tracked us with that scenario. `is_trivially_copyable` is indeed a good criterion - cool.

Comment: Of course, if the user has in mind _other_ invariants in mind that are not maintained by the copy constructor, but rather by some external mechanism or rule (e.g., after you copy this object, update some pointer on it via a method call) then such objects aren't suitable to be used in containers at all (they will break regardless of whether the byte-wise copy optimization is used). (I wrote this at the same time time as my earlier two comments, but it didn't get submitted, but yeah it seems we are in violent agreement here).

Comment: I decided to ask about `realloc` specifically [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46838729/149138). The quick summary is that by a strict reading of the standard, even `memcpy` can't be used to "create" an object in uninitialized storage (you need placement `new` to do that), so `realloc` is probably technically not allowed to move objects since it gives you no chance to create the objects and is not defined to do so. Bleh.

Comment: *"by a strict reading of the standard, even memcpy can't be used"* - your phrasing makes it sound like a strictly conforming compiler/implementation isn't allowed to have memcpy work, but the situation is that the Standard doesn't *require* an implementation to support memcpy (or aiming a pointer at memory from another language, network packet, shared memory etc. for that matter), but implementations are fully allowed to define behaviour that's left undefined by the Standard, and there's wide support.  Whether that's good enough is for the programmer/team/company to decide.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Unfortunately, the Standard fails to make any distinction between constructs which implementations should be expected to support reliably absent an obviously-good or documented reason for doing otherwise, with those which few if any implementations should be expected to support reliably, and the maintainers of compilers that are popular by virtue of being open-source interpret the Standard's failure to mandate behavior as being a good enough reason in and of itself to deviate from commonplace behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good reason why C++ doesn't have `realloc`; instead of repeating it, I'll point you to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3105769/541686).

And for the record, a proper `vector` implementation mitigates the fragmentation issue to some extent, [**by choosing a growth factor close to the golden ratio**](http://crntaylor.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/optimal-memory-reallocation-and-the-golden-ratio/), so it's not completely a lost cause.

Comment: I'm not sure how their explanation helps; they don't say *why* it prohibits C `realloc`, only that it does. C and C++ memory allocation aren't supposed to interact so I don't understand why there could be a `cplusplusrealloc` which doesn't interfere with C memory allocation but can be used with `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @BenHymers: It's explained on the page they link to. The problem is the fact that `realloc` *copies* raw memory, which means it doesn't work for C++ because C++ requires using copy-constructors. Yes, they could have added a *different* reallocation function instead, but they explain the reason why they didn't do that: *"This in turn would have added complexity to many allocator implementations, and would have made interaction with memory-debugging tools more difficult. Thus we decided against this alternative."*

Comment: Haha, deciding not to add something to C++ because it would add complexity, that makes me chuckle :) But ok, it's an explanation, fair point.

Comment: @BenHymers: I know, right? I suppose back then it wasn't *quite* the monster it is now. =P

Answer (score 1):

> `std::vector` fragments memory as it grows because C++ has no equivalent of `realloc`.

`realloc` will fragment the memory in the same way, since it's doing the same thing - allocating a new block and copying the contents, if the old block wasn't large enough.

> With great care, couldn't you write something that works just like `std::vector` but using C allocation functions, which has the possibility to grow its memory without moving its address and copying existing elements, making it as good or better in terms of fragmentation and performance?

That's just what `vector` does. You can control the *capacity* independently of the *size*, and it will only reallocate when the capacity is exceeded. `realloc` is similar, but with no means to control the capacity - making `vector` better in terms of fragmentation and performance.

> why doesn't C++ have an equivalent to `realloc`?

Because it has `std::vector`, which does the same thing with more flexibility. As well as allowing you to control exactly how and when memory is allocated, it works with any movable type, while `realloc` will go horribly wrong when used with non-trivial types.

Comment: "realloc will fragment the memory in the same way" - not necessarily; it might extend the existing memory block, that's the point :)

Granted, a `realloc`-based container would fail for non-trivial types, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: @BenHymers: "it might extend the existing block" - or it might not, and you have no way to control that. If fragmentation matters, then `vector` gives you the tools to manage it, using `reserve` or a custom allocator; `realloc` just does whatever it does. If fragmentation doesn't matter, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ... but it also might! I'm happy if peformance and memory usage patterns are occasionally randomly *better* than normal. `vector` gives me some tools, sure, but it can't allow me to extend an existing memory allocation. And `reserve` only helps if I have an idea of capacity beforehand.

Comment: The "point" that `std::vector` has all these controls to manage capacity and size such as `reserve` while `realloc` doesn't make no sense to me. `realloc` is not a container. We are talking about implementing a container, _like_ `vector`, _on top of_ `realloc`. Obviously a good implementation of such a container would also have a "size" and "capacity" and wouldn't blindly call `realloc` every time an element was added (which would likely have terrible performance and lead to fragmentation).

Comment: Now you'd have something with the same worst-case performance, functionality and so on as `vector`, but sometimes you'd get the "free win" of being able to leave your elements in-place and not have to copy them on an expand - with all the memory bandwidth, cache thrashing and CPU time that involves. Of course, the downside is that it only works with trivially copyable types (technically it can work with any types which are "bit-wise movable" but C++ hasn't formalized such a concept yet).