# C and C++ weird performance difference

Tags: c++, c, performance, benchmarking

Before you read my post, please take into consideration that I am new to both C and C++.
I'm mostly a managed code developer.

I have two pieces of identical code (or that's what I believe at least).
One in C and one in C++.
The code basically checks if the number is a prime, and if it is, it will store it in a container.

C++

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

static bool isPrime(const int& number) {

    if((number & 1) == 0) {
        if(number == 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    for(int i = 3; (i * i) <= number; i++) {

        if((number % i) == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return number != 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<int> vector;
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 30000000; i++) {

        if(isPrime(i))
            vector.push_back(i);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    clock_t seconds = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "done after " << seconds << " seconds " << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

C

Vector.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct vector_class {
    void(*push_back)(struct vector_class *vector_instance, const int *data);
    int *data;
    int length;
    int capacity;
} vector;

static void push_back(vector *vector_instance, const int *data) {

    if(vector_instance->length >= vector_instance->capacity) {

        vector_instance->capacity *= 2;
        vector_instance->data = (int*) realloc(vector_instance->data, sizeof(int) * vector_instance->capacity);
    }
    vector_instance->data[vector_instance->length] = *data;
    vector_instance->length++;
}

static void vector_constructor(vector *vector_instance) {

    vector_instance->push_back = &push_back;
    vector_instance->length = 0;
    vector_instance->capacity = 2;
    vector_instance->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*vector_instance->data) * vector_instance->capacity);

}

static void vector_destructor(vector *vector_instance) {

    free(vector_instance->data);
    vector_instance->length = 0;
    vector_instance->capacity = 0;
    vector_instance->data = NULL;
}
```

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vector.c"
#include <time.h>

static int isPrime (const int *number) {

    if((*number & 1) == 0) {
        if(*number == 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 3; (i * i) <= *number; i += 2) {

        if((*number % i) == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return *number != 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector v;
    vector_constructor(&v);
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 30000000; i++) {

        if(isPrime(&i))
            v.push_back(&v, &i);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    clock_t seconds = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%lu seconds \n", seconds);

    for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {

        //printf("%d \n", v.data[i]);
    }
    vector_destructor(&v);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile both programs on my OS X Mavericks, with the built in Clang compiler.

C++

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 Main.cpp
```

C

```
gcc -O3 -std=c99 Main.c
```

Both get compiled trouble free, and they also run trouble free.
However..

I get different time results.

C finishes after **12 seconds**

C++ finishes after **26 seconds**

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not quite the same - the loop in `isPrime` has different increments. Not sure if this'd make a difference though.

Comment: It's hilarious that your C code is calling push_back through a function pointer and it is still much faster than your C++.  But I think the different loop increments are the main reason for the performance difference.  Your C++ version is likely doing twice as many moduli as your C version.

Comment: Also, the STL `vector` may have different rules for expanding its capacity. If it, say, uses `capacity *= 1.5`, it'll call `new` more times.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I think it would make that much of a difference.  The C++ version is checking twice as many divisions and is running about twice as long.

Comment: @Daniel, try to make two different tests. First - adding in vector N numbers in C and C++, second - Checking IsPrime(...) M times.
That will help you to understand where is problem, in function or in vector.

I guess that increasing +2 in C vs increasing +1 in C++ may give twice more operations in C++, so that may be reason of your result.

Comment: Thanks guys.
I did modify the loops, from ++ to +=2.
And changed the C vector from *2 to *1.5
C is still faster than C++ by 3 seconds, but I guess thats compiler optimisation.

Comment: Unrelated to the optimization: The way you are using the C version's push_back with passing the address of i; you are passing the same address each time.  And the value at that address is changing in each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Interestingly, on my machine, after fixing the loop iterator, the C runs in 12.78 seconds and the C++ in 12.81 -- basically the same.  (I used `time ./prime` on UNIX to get more granularity on the time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your programs are subtly different in `isPrime`.  In your C++ program:

```
for(int i = 3; (i * i) <= number; i++) {
```

In your C program:

```
for(int i = 3; (i * i) <= *number; i += 2) {
```

So, your C++ program is computing the remainder about twice as many times as your C program, which likely explains your performance discrepancy.

Beyond that, I recommend that you not pass `int` by reference or pointer unless you have a good reason.  Hopefully, the compiler would be smart enough to figure out that you didn't need to and optimize that out, but who knows?

Also, you want to avoid calling functions through function pointers, like you do in your C program, when you can.  They usually hurt a compiler's ability to inline optimize functions.  It might be the case here that the compiler is smart enough to inline the call anyway, but again who knows?

Finally, if computing all primes less than N is really what you are after and this just isn't a toy to benchmark C vs. C++, then look into the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or the [Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram).  Alternatively, you can pass your vector of already known primes into `isPrime` and check only against already known primes rather than all odd numbers.

Comment: Thank you, That helped significantly.
However, it is still 4 seconds slower. Is there something else that I have overseen?

Comment: Someone else remarked that a common implementation of vector grows its capacity by 1.5 rather than 2 each time.  You could change your C program to grow by 1.5 rather than 2 each time and see if that closes the gap entirely.

Comment: I changed that as well, it keeps getting closer.
C finishes after 11 seconds.
C++ finishes after 13 seconds..
I guess this is optimal enough for me :)

Comment: @jshultz410: GCC supposedly also uses a factor of 2x. Personally I would tend to suspect `realloc`. A std::vector ought to copy over the data manually while `realloc` may use `mremap` or other tricks to avoid the copying.

Comment: Try adding `vector.reserve( 5,761,455 );` That will completely eliminate all the `std::vector<>` reallocations and you'll run a lot faster.

Comment: @doynax I'd be surprised if std::vector didn't have an optimized template for POD's (or at least pointers) that pulled the same kind of tricks.

Comment: @RobK hopefully you mean `vector.reserve(5761455);` rather than using the comma operator!

Comment: @jschultz410: Possibly but I had trouble making GCC generate `realloc` the last time I tried, which admittedly was a while back. It would need to bypass the allocator interface, and specialize on POD together with the standard allocator.

Comment: @jschultz410 I doubt you will find a standard library that uses `realloc` in any version of `vector`. They all go through the allocator interface, which doesn't support anything `realloc`-like.

Comment: Yes, I meant to clip those commas out!

Comment: That's interesting that they didn't put a realloc like interface into std::allocator considering that C had that approach for so long.  A default implementation that used allocate, memcpy and deallocate could easily be provided.  Then only containers that could benefit from it need use it.  I guess vector, deque and unordered_map of POD's might be the only containers to benefit from it, so they considered it not worth complicating the interface ...

Comment: On my systemwith mingw-4.9.2-x86_64, both take 66 seconds . Note that this program does not really test vector, since nearly all of the processing time is spent doing divisions. , for which both versions generate effectively the same assembly. You could use something like gprof to see where time is spent.

Comment: @jshultz410: Perhaps but since when did the C++ committee give a toss about not complicating the language? *Grumble..*

Comment: @jschultz410 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105001/why-is-there-no-reallocation-functionality-in-c-allocators