# How do I use use std::allocator in place of realloc?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, realloc, allocator

Let's say I'm writing a custom vector using the `std::allocator` to wrap `new` and `delete`.

When the number of elements exceed the vector's capacity, I would like to reallocate the buffer to something larger.  I can achieve this easily by calling `realloc()`.  I don't want to do this though because I thought the responsibility of allocation/deallocation should reside in the allocator.

Yet, looking at `std::allocator`'s interface, I don't see how I could do a reallocation.  There are only methods for:

```
T* allocate( std::size_t n );
void deallocate( T* p, std::size_t n );
```

Should I be calling `allocator::allocate` and then `allocator::deallocate` instead of just `realloc`?  Is that as efficient?  It must be what `std::vector` is doing as well.  Why does `std::allocator` not provide a `reallocate` function?

Comment: _"Why does std::allocator not provide a reallocate function?"_ This is covered somewhat in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105001/why-is-there-no-reallocation-functionality-in-c-allocators?rq=1).

Comment: [FYI] https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#realloc-and-renew

Comment: @NathanOliver It ends by stating "In C++, a better way of dealing with reallocation is to use a standard library container, such as vector, and let it grow naturally.", which is the starting point of this question...

Comment: @AmiTavory And round and round it goes ;) Just pointing out to the OP that mixing new and realloc is not a good idea.

Comment: @NathanOliver You have a point, and the comment is indeed pertinent. Sorry if I mistakenly gave the impression I thought it wasn't.

Comment: No problem.  The ... at the end made me think there was something wrong with it.  No worries though.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that while `realloc` operates on a lower level than, say, `std::vector`’s capacity, they both do fundamentally the same thing, and implementing reallocation yourself using a combination of `allocate`, `deallocate` and moving should be expected to be just as efficient (probably more efficient in general, since we can provide hints in the form of a capacity): `realloc` isn’t performing magic, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let's say I'm writing a custom vector using the std::allocator to wrap new and delete.

In the general case (excluding specializations for PODs), I don't think you could use `realloc` in any case. An arbitrary object, constructed at a specific memory location, might have internal pointers pointing to very specific addresses in relation to the address in which it was constructed. Simply moving it around (in the byte-copying sense) could break invariants.

Thus the alternative you mention is in general necessary. You would have to allocate a new array, `move` (or possibly even `copy`!) the objects to the new location, then deallocate the old array. Of course, this includes more than a single stage that can fail - another reason why you can't really `reallocate` in the general case. Perhaps this is the reason that allocators never had this functionality in the first case - for array-based containers, you can't really use them in general (although you might be able to use them for POD specializations).